# Is it possible to solo the larger Underdome challenges?

Tags: borderlands, borderlands-mad-moxxis-underdome

I have completed the small challenges in all 3 arenas by myself and I wonder how hard the waves become towards the later rounds of the larger challenges.

Is it too difficult to complete the larger challenges alone? Is it worth doing alone?

Comment: "Is it worth doing alone?" Only if you actually enjoy the challenge. The reward vs time is virtually nil. You get one skill point for all challenges which could easily take 3hrs each. So is 9 - 12 hours of your time (of which you cannot save and can only stop in between rounds) worth the skill point? Also, NOTE: failing a round will make you start from the round before!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its worth doing if you want the skill point as reward at the end of the quest.  As for doing them solo, I know its fairly easy to do on Hell-Burbia as there's a spot you can jump up to (above the stack of crates) where the enemies cannot reach you.  As long as you have a class mod that regenerates whatever ammo you use (I prefer sniper rifles in those situations), you'll be fine.

The Angelic Ruins and Gully don't have easy hiding spots so it entirely depends on what character you have but its much more difficult to solo due to the different enemies that spawn in those areas (I have never had the patience to fully attempt either one to completion with any of my characters).

I would suggest joining a game with another character who's at much lower level than you, as the enemies will be scaled to fit their level and then you'll have a much easier time to complete the missions.

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like it's possible then. I'll give it a shot. Going to take forever!

Comment: @Mike tell me how it goes.  Some day I might pick up borderlands again, I have many fond memories of that game

Comment: just posted my findings for attempting this tonite in case you're interested

Comment: The Angelic Ruins and the Gully do have spots where you can't be (easily) reached, which is good for horde waves, but you're going to often be dealing with the guardians in the badass wave so you can't stay really get away with camping too much.

Answer (score 2):

Completed all at Level 69 Solo last year and it took me months even with some of best Cyan weapons. There's some Luck involved and a lot of strategy especially when your suddenly punished with Naked and Vampire and close combat at the same time against a Boss almost always = do over to previous level BEGINNING (The OUCH Factor of the Dome Challenges).  Each of the domes has a Horde Wave (3rd wave during each) hiding area that can make that section easier.

Upper Gulley = Jump up crates to Tent top and use Launcher with Corrision on all Horde Waves. I often fight from the upper level but sometimes suddenly surrounded by 6+ Super Bad Ass armoured or Angelic's it's almost impossible and must be prepared to jump off the cliff or exit the door to lower level asap and if you get the bad luck of vampire/naked when fighting a Boss it can be impossible.  Don't do these challenges during a lightning storm because a power failure will destroy progress for that Dome.

Hellburbia =  Right side crates to rooftop as a Perch w/a caution against Boss Taylor Cobb as his Launcher can destroy you no matter where U hide especially if the game Brands you Naked or piles on other handicaps as you progress.

Angelic Ruins = Entry Ramp upper level (left side if facing it) jump to Ledge Perfect to fight Horde but don't stay there for other levels. Primary fight/defend point rest of waves is opposite end where you see an arrow point to becomes a kiddy corner with walk up ramps but must defend 180 degree's. There are times you must use the entire landscape here and for me this was the hardest especially at Level 69. Make sure you have a powerful SMG to grind thru Angelic's shields. There'll be much more close combat here. Took me months and last 20 waves took two days leaving it running overnight since you can't SAVE which is the insane part of these challenges. Satisfying but one of the biggest PITA's in my gaming experience.

For those doing just the "Prove Yourself" Five Rounders keep in mind that when you get to the fifth round you get a double handicap and double spawn because it'll seem like your cleaning house and done but then suddenly your surrounded as it makes for many do overs back to previous round beginning the ultimate Piss-off - always prepare for cover and escape from scenario's in all five rounds and it gets much worse on the 20's.

IMO the absence of Save feature in the Domes demo's a sick sadistic trait by the Programmers of this DLC. Your held hostage to finish or your screwed and five rounders are long but 20 rounders can be maddening - and this is not a place for quality weapon drops as 99.9999% SUCK.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to do this tonight and it sucked. Got to the 10th round and it was midnight already.

So to answer my own question: do this with friends, or at least with another low level character being the host so you can blow through the waves.

It was *not* a bad experience, I would just not recommend it because of the amount of time it takes to finish. Had I more patience, I would have finished it.

I don't have a lot of playing time during the week, so it was a waste of time for me.

Comment: that's pretty much the same conclusion I ended up with, haha

Answer (score 0):

It has taken me at least 4 days and probably around 24 hours of game time to get to round 18 so far. I have in excess of 3,000 kills so I've gone through at least 300 waves. I hope my computer doesn't crash or I'm going to be pissed. It is insanely hard at the last levels where you have 4 handicaps applied and the enemy's shields and health are significantly boosted.

Comment: Wait it seriously took that long? I played it two player and it was insane, like 2+ hours per, but that doesn't seem right.

Answer (score -1):

today i managed to beat the angelic ruins and the gulley solo... and my character is level 29... I'm going to complete hell burbia soon as well... it requires a way for you to regenerate health and a lot of guerrilla tactics

Comment: Can you elaborate more on these tactics? As it stands this doesn't really answer the question.